# Angular 2: expired-callback is not getting fired in google reCAPTCHA

Tags: angular, recaptcha

I've a form in my angular 2 application with google reCAPTCHA and I'm loading it like below.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" [attr.data-sitekey]="sitekey" expired-callback="expCallback" data-callback="verifyCallback"></div>
```

in corresponding component constructor I'm binding the expCallback like below.

```
constructor(private _accountsApi: AccountsApiService, private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.initForm();
    window['verifyCallback'] = this.recaptchaCallback.bind(this);
    window['expCallback'] = this.resetCaptcha.bind(this);
}

resetCaptcha() {
    grecaptcha.reset();
}
```

Now, if the user solves the Captcha and kept the page idle for 2 minutes. Now I'm getting error message on Captcha widget "**Verification expired. Check the checkbox again**"
When I get this error message, the `resetCaptcha()` method is not getting invoked.

Am I missing anything? Or is there any better way to reload the captcha when it gets expired?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to reset the validated / used recaptcha

`let myWindow: any = window;
myWindow.grecaptcha.reset();`

Currently you can call it a workaround only. For more updates, follow this thread at github:

[Link to this feature thread at GitHub](https://github.com/xmaestro/angular2-recaptcha/issues/16)

Comment: I want to reset the Captcha only when it gets expired. So, my question is
How to catch the expired Captcha event('expired-callback') so that I can reset it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this module that is developed for angular2 only.
Works quite nicely, with the callback.

[angular2-recaptcha](https://github.com/xmaestro/angular2-recaptcha)

Comment: Is there any way to declare 'expired-callback' attribute? So that I can reset the Captcha if it gets expired.

Comment: @dineshsharaf, https://github.com/xmaestro/angular2-recaptcha has been updated to get this feature. Please try and suggest if it works.

Answer (score 0):

` It works for me

```
$w:any = window;

constructor(){this.$w['verifyCallback'] = this.verifyCallback.bind(this);}`
```